# How do I center header text in the middle of the navigation menu in html

Tags: html, css, center

I am wondering how to center the header text I wrote in the center of the navigation menu that I created, the text is already centered but it is centered at the top of the navigation menu, not in the middle, which is what I need.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<style>
    body {margin:0;}
    .Header {
        z-index: 100;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #000000;
        height: 70px;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width:680px) {
        .Header.responsive {position: relative;}
        .Header.responsive li.icon {
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
        }

    }
    @media (max-width: 960px){
    .Header .headerLogo{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 86px;
        height: 15px;
        margin-top: 17px;
        margin-left: 6px;
    }
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="Header" id="myHeader">
    <a class = "headerLogo">
    <header><center><i><font size = "6" face = "verdana" color = "white">Lunation Boards</font></i></center></header>
    </a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `<center>` and `<font>` elements are obsolete now

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**You have three options, *whereby the first two options are a lot more reliable*.**

The first option uses flex-box to center the item horizontally and vertically.

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: blue;
}

text {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <text>Centered horizontally and vertically</text>
</div>
```

The second option, instead of using flex-box, uses a relative position for the parent element, an absolute position for the child element, and `transform: translate(X, Y)` also for the child.

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background: blue;
}

text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <text>Centered horizontally and vertically</text>
</div>
```

The third option, in order to center the element vertically, uses a `line-height` that is equal to the `height` of the parent element.

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background: blue;
}

text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  line-height: 200px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <text>Centered horizontally and vertically</text>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick.

To clean up your HTML, set it up like this and remove tags like `<center>` and `<font>`:

```
<div class="Header" id="myHeader">
    <a class = "headerLogo">
        <h1>Lunation Boards</h1>
    </a>
</div>
```

And you can use `display: flex` to center things in your header:

```
.Header {
    z-index: 100;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 70px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

a {
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
}

@media (max-width: 960px){
.Header .headerLogo {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 86px;
    height: 15px;
    margin-left: 6px;
}
}
```

Here's the full fiddle with the changes:

https://jsfiddle.net/xqamjrvr/

Answer (score 0):

Try    (Your code here)   . Replace : (Your code here) with waht ever you want int he centre.

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you dont need to put `<center>` tag in the header, align it with css.
2. and also when you are using your own class you should remove the `<header>` tag .
3. You are using 100% width in header so you should not use left:0;
4. You need to use position: relative in headerlogo class with margin: 0 auto;

I have used html and css so far, but i think it will help

Here is the sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Home</title>
</head>
<style>
body {margin:0;}
.Header {
    z-index: 100;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 70px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
    .Header.responsive {position: relative;}
    .Header.responsive li.icon {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
    }

}
@media (max-width: 960px){
.Header .headerLogo{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 86px;
    height: 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="Header" id="myHeader">
<a class = "headerLogo">
<i><font size = "6" face = "verdana" color = "white">Lunation Boards</font></i>
</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```